# What is the Integral of $\ x^a e^{ax}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, chi-squared

Suppose we have the Chi-Square Probability Distribution Function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test):

$$f(x;k) = \frac{1}{2^{k/2}\Gamma(k/2)} x^{k/2-1} e^{-x/2}$$

**I am interested in learning how I can integrate the above function by myself:**

$$\int \frac{1}{2^{k/2}\Gamma(k/2)} x^{k/2-1} e^{-x/2} dx$$

To begin with, I can recognize that the first term in this integral is a constant with respect to $x$ . This means that I should be able to write this integral as:

$$\frac{1}{2^{k/2}\Gamma(k/2)} \int x^{k/2-1} e^{-x/2} dx$$

I think now I can write the remainder of this integral in generic where $a$ is some constant term and $x$ is the variable of interest:

$$\int x^a e^{ax} dx$$

**I do not know how to integrate the above expression** - I tried to search for references online that show how to integrate functions in the above form, but I could not find anything (closest I could was [Integrate $e^{-ax}$ and $xe^{-ax}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639239/integrate-e-ax-and-xe-ax)). And I am not sure how the information from this reference can be adapted to solve the integral I am working on.

**My Question:**

- Can someone please show me how to integrate the above function?
- And after successfully integrating this function - can we then show that entire Chi-Square Probability Distribution Function integrates to $1$ over $\infty, -\infty$ ?

Thanks!

**References:**

- [Integrate $e^{-ax}$ and $xe^{-ax}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639239/integrate-e-ax-and-xe-ax)

Comment: What about the incomplete gamma function ?

Answer (score 4):

If $k$ is an even integer, say, $k = 2m + 2 \geq 2$, then applying integration by parts $m$ times yields $$\int x^{\frac{k}{2} - 1} e^{-\frac{x}{2}} \,dx = -2 e^{-\frac{x}{2}} \cdot m! \sum_{j=0}^m \frac{1}{j!} (2 x)^j + C.$$
(Cf. [OEIS A161381](https://oeis.org/A161381).) In this case, the normalization constant $\frac{1}{2^\frac{k}{2} \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}$ specializes to $\frac{1}{2^{k + 1} m!}$.

If $k$ is not an even integer, however, the antiderivative of the probability density function
$$x^{\frac{k}{2} - 1} e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$$
of the chi-squared distribution does not have an antiderivative expressible in terms of elementary functions. The incomplete gamma function,
$$\Gamma(x, s) := \int_s^\infty e^{-t} t^{x - 1} \,dt ,$$
which Claude Leibovici mentioned in the comments, is almost purpose-built for this sort of situation. Given the integral
$$\int x^{a - 1} e^{-b x} \,dx, \qquad a > 0, \quad b > 0,$$
the substitution $t = b x$, $dt = b \,dx$ quickly yields the antiderivative
$$-\frac{1}{b^a} \Gamma(a, b x) + C .$$

In particular, the integral over $[0, \infty)$ is
$$\int_0^\infty x^{a - 1} e^{-b x} \,dx = \frac{\Gamma(a)}{b^a} ,$$
where $\Gamma(x) = \Gamma(x, 0) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{x - 1} \,dt$ is the usual gamma function.

For the chi-squared distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom, we have $a = \frac{k}{2}$, $b = \frac{1}{2}$, so the cumulative density function is
$$\frac{1}{2^\frac{k}{2} \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)} \int_0^s x^{\frac{k}{2} - 1} e^{-\frac{x}{2}} \,dx = 1 - \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}, \frac{s}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)},$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2^\frac{k}{2} \Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)} \int_0^\infty x^{\frac{k}{2} - 1} e^{-\frac{x}{2}} \,dx = 1 ,$$
as expected.

If $k$ is an odd integer, we can express the antiderivative of the p.d.f. using elementary functions and the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Answer (score 0):

**Incomplete Gamma Function**

Letting $y=bx$ transforms the integral into
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^{a-1} e^{-y} \frac{d y}{b} \\
& =\frac{1}{b^a} \int y^{a-1} e^{-y} d y \\
& =\frac{1}{b^a} \Gamma(a, y)\\&=\frac{1}{b^a} \Gamma(a, b x)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\Gamma(k,z)$ is a [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).